# gitlab-runner: Segmentation Fault? How to solve this?

Tags: deployment, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd, gitlab-runner

I have been trying to figure out what's the problem with gitlab-runner,I have installed gitlab-runner on unix. it suddenly shows an error "Segmentation fault (core dump)". I tried to reinstall gitlab-runner, or check status. every command i try then it genereated an error. how to fix this error?

Comment: Would love to know if you found any solutions to this issue.

Comment: I'm having this problem right now with GitLab runner version 16.4.1 on Ubuntu 22.04. I've tried a few different installation methods too. I don't get it.